# CSS: Scrollbar pushes my site-header, but not my css-inner, and it results in uneven widths

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Just click any post to see what I mean, here's

I want to either:

1.make whole site pushable by scrollbar, so header and body have even widths

or

2.make whole site not pushable by scrollbar.

How can I do that? Maybe its because my header is 100% of width, while my body is fixed value (i think it is, dont remember).

Any help appreciated, ive been working on this website css for 2 weeks and my brain already wanted to give up

Comment: As much as I can tell, the widths are uneven regardless of the scrollbar. It's just not visible on the frontpage because your `.blog artcile` have a padding themselves. Remove it to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @TheFrozenOne yeah that was it. i thought i added padding on post pages as well (and i did) but i added it to wrong div.

I fixed it already.

PS, sorry for not providing code.